# no member named 'KInt16' in namespace 'torch'

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

I am working on a cpp extension for pytorch, and followed the official tutorial, using libtorch and cmake to compile the program. But I met the problem of creating tensor.
This code can work.

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::vector<int64_t> test_data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    torch::Tensor s = torch::from_blob(test_data.data(), {3, 3}, torch::kInt64);
    std::cout << "test case pass" << std::endl;
}
```

But this code can't work.

```
int main(){
    auto option = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::KInt16);
    auto b = torch::zeros({2,3}, option);
    std::cout << "test case pass" << std::endl;
}
```

and the compile error log is here.

```
error: no member named 'KInt16' in namespace 'torch'; did you mean 'kInt16'?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explicitly stated by the error message, you made a typo : you should have written
`torch::kInt16` instead of `torch::KInt16`. The `k` should not be capitalized.